# How to get a count in the foreign key item?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I need get all `bank` where `BankBranches cityId = filter.CityId > 0`

Code:

```
 banks = from bank in banks
            where bank.BankBranches.Where(y => y.CityId == filter.CityId).Count() > 0
            select bank;
    var list = banks.ToList();
```

Error:

> Access to the member 'Int32 CityId' from 'Model.Entities.BankBranch' not allowed for type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable `a [Model.Entities.BankBranch].

Comment: can you give some more information about the framework you are using (For example Entity Framework <version> - <Code First/Model First>  or Linq to SQL)

Comment: also can you give information about the `BankBranches` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
banks = from bank in banks
        join bankBranche in m_banksRepository.BankBranches on bank.Id equals bankBranche.BankId
        where bankBranche.CityId == filter.CityId
        select bank;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 banks = from bank in banks.Include(p=>p.BankBranches)
            where bank.BankBranches.Where(y => y.CityId == filter.CityId).Count() > 0
            select bank;
    var list = banks.ToList();
```